# Saving/updating one to many relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm wondering what the best approach is when saving (for the first time) or updating one-to-many relationships with Laravel.

At a simple level I have a `Person` model which can have multiple `Appointment` models associated to it. These relationships are established on the models themselves, but now I need to be able to;

- Display them when editing a `Person`
- Allow them to be saved in the first instance
- Allow them to be updated in future

The tricky part is that I want them to be embedded within the form for editing the `Person` itself, rather than on a separate page. So, the fields for the `Appointment`s are shown within an expandable table, in the middle of the `Person` form.

So far I've managed to send the form data in a way which means I get an array which contains the full details of the `Appointment` models, which I could probably convert into `Appointment` models and then save them. It doesn't feel very elegant though, and I'm thinking there is probably a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran across this a few days earlier, and figured that the best way to modify all appointments, was to send the data, and loop between all the database entries and update them one by one. Ofcourse you wouldn't be able to have a single function for both creating and modifying the appointments so you are looking at possibly two views for your end user. One for creating appointments, and one for ammending them.

So, if your data sent look something like:

```
appointment[0]
appointment[1]
appointment[2]
```

Within your controller, you can do a query to retrieve all appointments, such like

```
$appointments = Appointment::where('user_id','=',$userid)->get();
```

and do a loop, of each appointment to update the contents using a foreach.

```
$i=0;
foreach($appointments as $appointment){
    $appointment->date = Input::get('appointment')[$i];
    $appointment->save();
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: That's similar to how I was thinking of doing it. The big problem I ran into is how to handle dynamically created rows (i.e. I had an "Add appointment" button which would use JavaScript to insert a new row containing blank fields, and giving those fields unique names was proving to be a bit tricky). I think I've settled on putting the appointment creation form on a separate page for now (and listing all of them below the person details page), as it seems to be the easiest and most robust solution for the time being.

Comment: I have done the same exact thing on a single page, but it's slightly complicated. My approach was the following: Created a hidden field with the id of the database entry and gave them a name of appointment_ch[0] etc. Then I created another hidden field with a name: appointment_type[0] etc which had 2 possible values. 'new' or 'update'. So that I could handle each of them accordingly within my function, but it's not really recommended as any user could change it by using the inspect element.